# Make a pygtk stock icon "unavailable"

Tags: python, pygtk

I have a toolbar that has the typical buttons: new, save, save as, etc. Is there a way to gray out/disable/make unavailable icons that are not useful?

For instance, if nothing has been changed, disable and gray out the save button, then re-enabled it when something has changed that requires a save.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You've tried making the buttons not "sensitive" (GTK-speak for greyed-out)?

Comment: Perfect, that's what I needed. Thanks. I am new to pygtk and my Googling was not using the correct terminology. Want to answer the question that way so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myButton.set_sensitive(True)    # make button available

myButton.set_sensitive(False)    # make button unavailable